# Add row in .csv file after comparison with pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I analyze the data in relation to the covid-19 of a certain region of Brazil, where I collect the data through a connection to an api. The complete work is [here](https://github.com/ghmc91/Covid-19_data_analysis). I need to open a .csv file and add the last row of the dataframe below as long as the epidemiological_week value of this dataframe is different from that value for the same column in the .csv file.

[image]

what I'm trying to do (I haven't been able to compare yet, I'm just trying to add the last row of the dataframe):

```
with open('/home/gustavo/Desktop/CsvCovid/csvBso/BoletimEpidemiologicoResumido' + last_thu_str + '.csv', 'a') as fd:
    fd.write(dfBso.tail(1))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can just open in a text editor and modify. CSV is just comma separated values

Comment: Which error do you get? The separator may be not comma or the file location might be wrong. Try with `read_csv` from `pandas`

Comment: the error I make is precisely when writing to the file: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not DataFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a dataframe row to a CSV file, you can try this:

- Read the csv using Pandas **read_csv**
- Convert the last dataframe row to csv string with **to_csv** and **StringIO**
- Append the csv string to the csv file using the basic **open** function

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

dfcsv = pd.read_csv("Covid.csv") # sample set
dfcsv.iloc[len(dfcsv)-1,2]='2020-08-20' # update last row for test

s = io.StringIO() # text stream
dfcsv.iloc[[len(dfcsv)-1]].to_csv(s, header=False, index=False) # get last df row

with open('CovidNew.csv', 'a') as fd:  # file to append to
    fd.write(s.getvalue())  # add new csv row
```